# How to make rviz2 startup navigation automatically

Tags: ros, ros2, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, in my project, I open multiple instances of rviz2, one for each robot. Every time, I need to press the "`Startup`" button in Rviz for the map to show and I can publish an initial pose from a seperate script.

[image: image description]

I want this to happen from the launch file and I thought the `autostart` launch parameter would do this, but it does not, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

There also does not seem to be a difference in the `.rviz` configuration file after pressing startup.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399321/how-to-make-rviz2-startup-navigation-automatically/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2022-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `autostart` launch parameter should be good enough, can you share you launchers?

You can base your launcher on this one here: https://github.com/SteveMacenski/nav2_rosdevday_2021

Concretely this part:

```
bringup_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        os.path.join(nav2_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
    launch_arguments={'slam': slam,
                      'map': map_yaml_file,
                      'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                      'params_file': params_file,
                      'autostart': 'True'}.items())
```

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on 2022-04-22**:
Yes, mine looks the same with `autostart` set to `True`.
My problem was that I have separated the `global planner` from the rest of the nav stack and launching that and `rviz` on a separate machine from the simulation.

After enabling `autostart` on the simulation machine, it worked...
I wonder what lifecycle node is needed for `rviz` to do it?